# How to reduce the error of tensorflow model?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Who can suggest how to improve the model?

The regular model in sklearn `LinearRegression()` predicts temperature with an error of 1 and the error of the model built manually on tensorflow won't drop below 5.5, no matter the activation function, the number of layers, or epochs.

The data was both standardized and derived into positive values

```
def createModelG(inputShape, dropout, initW):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4096,
        kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
        activation = 'elu',
        kernel_initializer = initW,
        input_dim = inputShape
    )) 
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    #for i in range(3):
    #    model.add(Dense(512, activation = 'relu'))
    #    model.add(Dropout(dropout))

    model.add(Dense(1024,
        kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.001),
        activation = 'elu'
    ))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(
        loss = 'mae',
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.0000005),
        metrics = ['mse', 'mae']
    )
    return model


startModelTest = crossValdation(createModelG, trainDataXS, 0.01, 'truncated_normal', 'VancouverT', PrintDot())
modelTest = startModelTest[1]
hist = startModelTest[2]
startModelTest[0]

    loss    mse mae val_loss    val_mse val_mae
0   22.6255 737.889 21.3214 7.32549 55.3201 6.02149
1   21.6446 677.313 20.3387 7.83092 64.0345 6.5251
2   21.1013 646.857 19.7952 7.00224 49.6842 5.69622
3   22.3446 712.008 21.0386 8.07596 68.7968 6.77008
4   24.2565 874.824 22.9531 7.71605 65.3973 6.41274
0   --- --- --- --- --- ---
0   22.3945
```

link to all code and result of my keras model and ready sklearn models:

https://www.kaggle.com/alihanurumov/weather-prediction-network

Comment: You need to add a few details to your question; there is no information on the actual data, what is the error term used, the sklearn code or the training/test code implemented. You should also remove the images and replace with code and output.

Comment: I came up with)) I will attach a link to the full code. Where can I see how much worse my model on Keras Tensor flow works (((

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def createModelG(inputShape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4096, input_dim = inputShape, 
                    kernel_initializer = initializers.glorot_uniform(seed = 1), 
                    kernel_regularizer = keras.regularizers.l2(0.01), activation = "relu")) 
    model.add(Dense(2048, 
                    kernel_initializer = initializers.glorot_uniform(seed = 1), activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(2048, 
                    kernel_initializer = initializers.glorot_uniform(seed = 1), activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1024, 
                    kernel_initializer = initializers.glorot_uniform(seed = 1), activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1024, 
                    kernel_initializer = initializers.glorot_uniform(seed = 1), activation = "relu"))
    model.add(layers.Dropout(0.05))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 0.000001)
    model.compile(loss = 'mse', optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ["mse", "mae"])
    return model
```